# Solve the equation $10x^2+11x+4=8(x+1)\sqrt{2x^2+x-1}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

Sovle the equation $10x^2+11x+4=8(x+1)\sqrt{2x^2+x-1}$.

I tried put $\sqrt{2x^2+x-1}= t,\; (t \geq0)$, so we have : ${2x^2+x-1}= t^2$ and  $10x^2+11x+4=8(x+1)t$.

Comment: This just doesn’t seem like it should be solvable by hand. Do you expect a nice answer? I tried plugging in Wolfram Alpha and got a horrible answer.

Comment: @benkei: Perhaps you didn't correctly copy the equation? If it's correctly written, perhaps you are expected to solve graphically or numerically?

Comment: @BenjaminWang After squaring, the problem reduces to finding the roots of a quartic polynomial.  This is, in principle, doable by hand.  If you believe otherwise, Cardano would like to have a word without you.  On the other hand, the computation is long and tedious, thus your second question is appropriate:

Comment: @benkei : Is there any reason to suppose that this equation has "nice" solutions?  Where did you encounter the problem?  Is if from a class of some kind?  If so, which class (for example, answers for an algebra/precalc class will look very different from those for a course in numerical analysis)?

Answer (score 1):

Given $$10x^2+11x+4=8(x+1)\sqrt{2x^2+x-1}$$
  If we divide both sides by $8(x+1)$, square both sides, and subtract the right side, we get

$$\bigg(\frac{10 x^2 + 11 x + 4}{8 (x + 1)}\bigg)^2 - \bigg(\sqrt{2 x^2 + x - 1}\bigg)^2 = 0$$
Expanding, we get
$$28 x^4 + 100 x^3 - 9 x^2 - 152 x - 80 = 0$$

There is a [quartic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function) but Wolfram Alpha gives and answer [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+28+x%5E4+%2B+100+x%5E3+-+9+x%5E2+-+152+x+-+80+%3D+0) as

$$\quad x≈-3.2368\quad x≈1.2880 \qquad x≈-0.81127 - 0.16488 i \qquad x≈-0.81127 + 0.16488 i $$

Comment: After squaring  you have to check if the resulting values are solutions of the original equation. Squaring is not an $\underline{\textrm{equivalent transformation}}$(!). But +1 for the rest.